# Como colocar a Tabs na parte superior do app

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, ionic

Preciso que minha tabs fique na parte de cima do app, mas ela fica normalmente na parte de baixo, alguem poderia me ajudar?

html:

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs preloadTabs="false">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Calculadora" tabIcon="ios-calculator"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Total" tabIcon="ios-cart"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Cadastro" tabIcon="ios-contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?
Caso seja ionic, tente esse codigo

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs tabsPlacement="top">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Calculadora" tabIcon="ios-calculator"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Total" tabIcon="ios-cart"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Cadastro" tabIcon="ios-contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Legal Pettrin, teria alguma link para referência sobre o posicionamento das Tabs?

Comment: Ola, LeAndrade, tenho sim! https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/

Comment: Valeu man, obrigado!